# Elliptic curve Jacobian coordinates example

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I am working on Matlab Jacobian coordinates, I want a jacobian coordinates example with numbers include doubling and additions based on `k` value to test the code if works properly? I tried to search in google to find any example, but I didn't find.

Can anyone refer to me a clear example includes numbers with answers to test my code

Thanks for all

Answer (score 3):

I have some test vectors included in the source code for [my `secp256k1` implementation called `ekliptic`](https://github.com/kklash/ekliptic/tree/main/test_vectors). This sounds like it might be similar to what you're after. *However...* you should probably convert Jacobian coordinates back to affine coordinates before comparing the results of Jacobian point addition/doubling operations. Here's why.

---

For any affine point $(x_a,y_a)$, there is an absurdly large number of possible Jacobian coordinate triplets $(x_j,y_j,z)$ which satisfy the requirements of Jacobian coordinates:

$$x_a = \frac{x_j}{z^2}$$

$$y_a = \frac{y_j}{z^3}$$

$z$ is basically a scaling factor we use to defer and accumulate division operations.

As a more concrete example, one could represent the affine point $(7,10)$ as the Jacobian $(x,y,z)$ points:

- $(7,10,1)$
- $(28,80,2)$
- $(63,270,3)$
- $(112,640,4)$
- etc etc.

As a result, I've found that different addition/doubling formulas will give me *different Jacobian coordinates.* For example, in my `ekliptic` library, I used [the `add-1998-cmo-2` formula](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-jacobian-0.html#addition-add-1998-cmo-2) for addition. But if I used a different addition formula to add the same two Jacobian points, I might get a different $(x_j,y_j,z)$ output. Indeed when i tried to scrape and reuse some test vectors from [the `btcec` project](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd/tree/master/btcec), i ran into exactly this issue, because they chose different formulas than I chose.

As long as two sets of Jacobian coordinates simplify to the same affine point $(x_a,y_a)$, they are still fundamentally equivalent, but this means that test vectors from one project *may* not be reusable for yours, without doing some conversions first.

Usually converting back to affine is simpler.

Comment: what is the a, b and p values you are using in your example?

Comment: I'm using the secp256k1 curve which is $y^2 = x^3 + 7$. You can look up those parameters online. 

Here's where they're defined in my library: https://github.com/kklash/ekliptic/blob/main/constants.go